# npm can't access private repo but browser can

Tags: java, node.js, maven, npm

we have corporate private repo with password. using browser i can easily get the file: `http://nexus.xxx.com/repository/npm-public/del/-/del-2.2.2.tgz` then i got a basic auth popup, i put username and password and i can download the npm package

but when i use npm (through `com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.3`) it freezes for a while and then reports an error:

```
[ERROR] npm ERR! fetch failed http://nexus.xxx.com/repository/npm-public/del/-/del-2.2.2.tgz
[WARNING] npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: socket hang up
[ERROR] npm ERR! fetch failed http://nexus.xxx.com/repository/npm-public/del/-/del-2.2.2.tgz
[WARNING] npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: socket hang up
[ERROR] npm ERR! fetch failed http://nexus.xxx.com/repository/npm-public/del/-/del-2.2.2.tgz
[ERROR] npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-72-generic
[ERROR] npm ERR! argv "/home/xxx/target/node/node" "/home/xxx/target/node/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "install"
[ERROR] npm ERR! node v4.2.6
[ERROR] npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
[ERROR] npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] npm ERR! network socket hang up
[ERROR] npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
[ERROR] npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
[ERROR] npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
[ERROR] npm ERR! network 
[ERROR] npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
[ERROR] npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
[ERROR] npm ERR!     /home/xxx/npm-debug.log
```

in setting.xml i have username and passwords, but i guess for some reason `frontend-maven-plugin` and therefore `npm` doesn't pick them up. how can i fix it?

Comment: according to their wiki the plugin supports passing npm arguments - can you put the password there? (could inject it from user home properties) https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/wiki

Comment: i don't know what are the npm arguments i should use

Comment: looking at a relevant npm issue (https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9325) seems to indicate youre supposed to place credentials in an `.npmrc` file. you can point npm to is using command line args found here - https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config and https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/npm